# Проблема с double

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, решил написать программу, в ней нужно сложить два дабловых числа...
И что, при сложении дабла 0.7 + 9 =9.699999999. Вот код:

```
g++;
for (int k = 0; k < g; k++) {
    r = r * 0.1;
}
r1 = r1 + r;
```

r- то самое 0.7, a r1=9... В чем ошибка??

Comment: What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вы уменьшили r в g раз там не получается 0.7, а как раз и получится 0.69999999, это связано с тем что компьютер работает в двоичной системе и там 10 - это 1010 - не круглое число.
Ошибки здесь нет, а если нужно проверять равенство потом, то можно проверить так:

```
eps=0.00001;
if (abs(r1-r2)<eps) 
{
 //...
}
```